# how to bfill in python adding a string like "(Copy)"

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Input and expected output]

Tried but does not work as expected
`df = df.fillna(method='bfill') + df.fillna('(Copy)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(df.bfill() + df.fillna(' (copy)').where(df.isna())).fillna(df)
```

Or

```
df.bfill().add(df.fillna(' (copy)').where(df.isna(), ''))
```

Output:

```
  column1     column2 column3      column4
0       a         cat   mouse       cheese
1       b  dog (copy)     NaN  food (copy)
2       c         dog     NaN         food
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @AJ12345 You may need to cast your df columns as strings first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) along with [`df.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html)

```
df_out = df.bfill() + np.where(df.notna(),'',' (Copy)')
df_out
  col1        col2   col3         col4
0    a         cat  mouse       cheese
1    b  dog (Copy)    NaN  food (Copy)
2    c         dog    NaN         food
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'